# Not Upload everything at once Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that searches a node on my firebase database and pulls a bunch of Image Url's from the node, and then displays the images linked to storage in a table view.

The problem is it will load every image, which could be hundreds of images. I would like to only do so many at a time to prevent data overuse.

Ideally it would sense when someone scrolling got close to the end, and then upload, say 10 more.

Thanks, I'm kinda just beginning so anything helps.

```
func loadthumbimages()
{
        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "ImageLocations/\(myspoits!)/\(DatesTableViewController.passdata!)")
        //observing the data changes
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0
            {
                //iterating through all the values
                for mydata in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                {
                    //getting values
                    let artistObject = mydata.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    // This is the data of the node
                    let fileURL  = artistObject?["fileURL"]
                    let thumbFileUrl  = artistObject?["thumbFileUrl"]
                    let ImageName = artistObject?["ImageName"]
                    //print(artistObject)
                    self.myarray1.append("\(ImageName!)")
                    self.myarray2.append("\(thumbFileUrl!)")
                    self.myarray3.append("\(fileURL!)")
                    //print(thumbFileUrl!)
                }
            }
        })
}
```

And here is my table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myarray1.count
}    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MycustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyimagecellTableViewCell   
   let urlString = "\(myarray2[indexPath.row])"

let url = URL(string: urlString)!
cell.myxcell.kf.setImage(with: url)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("row: \(myarray2[indexPath.row])")
    FetchdataViewController.fullimg = "\(myarray3[indexPath.row])"
    FetchdataViewController.thumbimg = "\(myarray2[indexPath.row])"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "photofull", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: One  way can be that you use `queryLimit` to fetch the data, first time you set the query limit to say `10` and then for the second time you set say `20` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for pagination - I have a method that always works for me.

You should limit your query to a paged amount such as 20, on the initial request. Also, you'll need to order your query by an incrementable index such as a timestamp, or a score. This key will act as our paging cursor to fetch the next set of images.

We can do so by getting the incrementable index value of the last object in your image array - for the sake of the example, we will use a timestamp as our incrementable index.

There is a `UITableViewDelegate` method called when a cell is about to show on screen. We can use this method to detect when we reach the twentieth cell and fetch the next batch of images using our cursor.

We can use either `queryStartingAtValue` or `queryEndingAtValue` to retrieve the images after/before our cursor and limit the query so we only get 20.